# How to re-arrange the data from rows containing dates to Quarterly columns in Excel automatically either by using formulas or Macros/VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to re-arrange the data in same excel sheet. The data have a column Period Date with dates in it and corresponding ROAA Values. I want to rearrange the ROAA values on the basis of Quarters columns picked from Period Date Column.

So that i can have ROAA values on the basis of Quarter and can delete duplicate rows and can have data of one bank in one row only.

[image]

I tried using formulas and managed to populate data quarterly, but need help in populating the same bank data in one row only and deleting the rest duplicate rows.

Comment: I think this might be easiest via a pivot table - you can right click on that `Period Date` and select group by Quarters - or do you need to maintain this in a regular sheet?

Comment: [No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Do some research on Pivot Tables.

Comment: I need to maintain this in a regular sheet as well..as i have to create Power BI reports on this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Pivot Tables to resume your data:

[image]

> [Create a PivotTable to analyze worksheet
> data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

I took field `Issuer Name` into rows section, field `Value` into Values section and `Date` into Columns Section.

Note I created a group in the date field, grouping by year **and** quarter.

> [Group or ungroup data in a
> PivotTable](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725)

Pivot Tables is your best option here, because if you add new rows to your table, you just need to update your Pivot Table and it will rearrange everything.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I can create Pivot table and move from there to create an actual datasheet using macros.